# Google Form jQuery AJAX request only works on Google Chrome

Tags: ajax, forms, google-forms

I am trying to get a form on my page to submit the responses to Google Forrms. It works fine on Google Chrome and Safari **locally**. However, I am hosting the project on GitHub pages, and when I view the website on GitHub pages, the form submission only works on Google Chrome, not on Safari. I assume, based on other answers, that the problem has to do with domain protection on AJAX requestions, but I am not quite if it is and how I would fix it (using jsonp doesn't work).

This is my HTML:

```
              <div class="img-rounded" style="background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <br>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form" background="black">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name">
                  </div>
                  &nbsp;
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                  </div>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="postContactToGoogle()">Sign up today</button>
                </form>
                </br>
              </div>
```

This is my JS code:

```
function postContactToGoogle() {

      var email = $('#email').val();
      var name = $('#name').val();

      $.ajax({
          url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1UkmyMxdlgfKnPDly5r8nOb1ZtRnxN9hJ3bDmavrJy8E/formResponse",
          data: { "entry_308291558": name, "entry_649840280": email },
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "xml",
          success: function (result) {
              $("#form-submit").html('Submitted');
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you are making a POST request to a Google Form?  Or to the form responses I guess.  I think you can simply embed the Google Form into your site.  I really don't understand the strategy you are using here.  I guess you want the responses to end up, . . . not in a spreadsheet, but in the form responses?

Comment: I want the responses to end up in a spreadsheet, I don't care how it gets there as long as I can format my form myself. But you're right, I guess I can copy the Google Form HTML and then format it to look how I want.

Comment: Open your Google Form in "Edit" mode.  In the "File" menu, there is an "embed" menu item.  Choose that, and you will be given the HTML to put into your site.  It will look like this `<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FormID/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>`